# sending alerts to slack when aws codepipeline is running

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

I created devop's pipeline using AWS codepipeline service.

my pipeline is

```
source: github
build : aws-codebuild
deploy: ECSdeploy
```

my pipeline is working fine with out any issue.

with the help of SNS,CLOUDWATCH event rules,LAMBDA, i am able to send alerts to slack

```
pipeline: <Name of the pipeline>
status : <status of pipeline STARTED/SUCCEEDED/FAILED>
```

**Question**

- I want to include GitHub merge number as part of alert

I am looking for slack alert something like this

```
pipeline: <Name of the pipeline>
status : <status of pipeline STARTED/SUCCEEDED/FAILED>
MERGE_ID : <GITHUB MERGE ID>
```

Can anyone suggestion a solution for this?

Comment: I doubt if merge is a singular item on a pipeline because it can contain multiple sources.  There is definitely a commit id available in codebuild, though....  And yet, that could be multiple as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the "CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION" environment var ?